# Find the longest word in a string recursively

Tags: java, string, recursion

How to find the longest word in a string recursively?

#### EDIT

Finished, thanks everyone. Here's the revised code.

```
public static String longestWord(String sentence)
{
    String longest;

    int i = sentence.indexOf(' ');

    if (i == -1)
    {
        return sentence;
    }

    String first = sentence.substring(0,i);
    first = first.trim();
    String rest = sentence.substring(i);
    rest = rest.trim();

    longest = stringcompare(first,longestWord(rest));

    return longest;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @john! Just so you know for the future, the formatter doesn't really like it when you mix tabs and spaces. I fixed it for you this time.

Comment: Assuming that this is either "homework" or an informal learning exercise, answers in the form of hints would be **most appropriate**.

Comment: just a pet peeve of mine: please don't uppercase method names or variables

Comment: You're talking about Word, right? That was an error on my part that I never got around to fixing. The instructor gave us the method names to use with an auto grading program, so I can't change them.

Comment: @john - 1) Get around to fixing "Word" ASAP.  Don't get into bad habits!!!  2) If your instructor *really* chose 'StringCompare' as a **method** name, he/she should not be teaching Java!  (My suspicion is that it is actually a class name ... and you've misread something.)

Comment: @john did the homework requirements include the method signature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all let's assume that the sentence string argument doesn't have any leading or trailing spaces. You are doing this for the recursive case by calling trim() which is sensible.

Then we need to define two cases, the base case and the recursive case.

The base case is where a space isn't found, i.e. the sentence passed in is just one word. In this case simply return the sentence.

In the recursive case we get the first word and the rest as you have done. Call longestWord on the rest of sentence. Then simply return the longest of the first word and whatever was returned by your recursive call.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that I just needed to split it once... recursion is still black magic to me. I'll post the revised code in case anyone wants to see.

Comment: @john: The thing about recursion is, when you write recursive code you only need to break the problem down once in the code-- because the code will call itself again, and again, as needed, until the problem is completely broken down. Then the subproblems can be solved and partial answers (i.e., longest words in PART of the sentence) can be returned by the recursive calls, until the original problem can be solved and then you have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1:

Break the problem down into two parts:

- split the string into the first word and the rest of the string
- find the longest of ...

Hint 2:

The problem is easier to solve if there are no leading and trailing spaces in the initial input string.

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.kota.java;
import java.util.*;

class LongestWord{
    String str = "Ram is intelligent boy";
    String stringArray[] = str.split("\\s");

    public String compare(String st1, String st2) {
        if (st1.length() > st2.length()) {
            return st1;
        } else {
            return st2;
        }
    }

    LongestWord() {
        String word = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                word = stringArray[0];
            }
            word = compare(word, stringArray[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("Longest word = " + word);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LongestWord();
    }
}
/**
 * Out put : Longest word = intelligent
 * 
 * */
```

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the string using

```
 String[] words = sentance.split(" ");
 String longest = null;
 String longestSize = 0;
 for (String str: words) {
    int size = str.length();

    if (longestSize < size) {
        longest = str;
        longestSize = size;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why was this voted up? I love this solution but it doesn't answer the question of how to do it RECURSIVELY...

Comment: never saw any requirement it had to use recursion, I can see no other reason to do this than for homework so it's a good job i never used recursion!

Comment: @Platinum without getting into a debate, I saw the question as a problem creating some correct code, the OP said they were doing it recursively, but did not say it was required to be recursive?  If someone said they were having problems cracking nuts with a hammer I'd show them how to use a nut cracker.

Comment: Well, if you take a closer look at the end of the question, you can see that this is for a class. In CS classes it's quite common to crack nuts with hammers. :-)

Comment: That was not part of the original question text, im out of here

Comment: Okay, this had been civil so far, but I'm sorry, your belligerence is making you look dumb. This answer is fundamentally unhelpful for the question as it was asked and you clearly can't be bothered to cater your responses to the actual question, so I'm downvoting this.