# longest word in java recursively

Tags: java, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find the longest word in a string recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455527/how-can-i-find-the-longest-word-in-a-string-recursively)

I need help in finding the longest word in java.. I think i got the base case right but the recursive is not working for me.. any help would be appreciated..

```
public static String longestWord(String sentence) {

        int spaceIndex = sentence.indexOf(" ");

        if (spaceIndex == -1) {
            return sentence;
        }

        String firstWord = sentence.substring(0, spaceIndex);

        String rest = sentence.substring(spaceIndex);
        rest = rest.trim();

        if (firstWord.length() >= longestWord(rest).length() ) {
            IO.outputStringAnswer(firstWord);
            return firstWord;
        }
        else {
            IO.outputStringAnswer(rest);
            return rest;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Does this need to be done recursively?

Comment: yes tht is da problem i know how to do it da other way.. tht is easy. i m stuck on da very last part of this..

Comment: what's the teacher's email? I need to speak with him/her...

Answer (score 0):

You just have to adapt your output in the else case - now it returns (and outputs) the rest of the sentence, while you want it to return the longest word of the rest.

---

To understand the problem, take a example sentence and some paper, and do your algorithm by hand.

- First, try it for simple sentences (one word, two words). It seems to work here.
- Next, take a 3-word sentence like `"Was it right"`?. Does it work here? If not, why? What do you need to change?

Comment: @user647207, what does "u" and "wht" mean?

Comment: @Paulo - I think you're example will work, because "what" is the longest.

Comment: @MByD: Thanks, you are right. I mis-thought here.

Answer (score 0):

It is almost correct, but you return wrong value in the else block.

Comment: You want to return the longest word between `first` and `longestWord(rest)` but what do you actually return if `longestWord(rest)` is longer?

Comment: the word that is the longest..

Comment: well, not exactly, you return the rest of the sentence...

Comment: i don't get what are you saying how can i return the rest of the sentence i need the longest word..

Comment: you can, if you by mistake `return rest;`